# Extracting a value in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash variable with the following value assigned to it:

```
# echo $b
{"tid": "session", "id": "9c7decd9-29d4-4d88-8fca-56d3b7b07bd5"}
```

When I try to extract the UUId from the variable `'b'`:

```
# temp=$(echo $b | awk '{print $4}')   
# echo $temp
"9c7decd9-29d4-4d88-8fca-56d3b7b07bd5"}
```

...I get the additional flower bracket at the end. How do I just get the UUID?

Thanks!

Comment: Can the person who down-voted the question please let us know why it was done so?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but we are up to our ears in near-duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep -oP` with a PCRE regex:

```
b='{"tid": "session", "id": "9c7decd9-29d4-4d88-8fca-56d3b7b07bd5"}'
temp=$(grep -oP '"id": +"\K[^"]+' <<< "$b")

echo "$temp"
9c7decd9-29d4-4d88-8fca-56d3b7b07bd5
```

Comment: The answer was generic and not dependent on the position of the value.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is JSON; so use [a JSON tool](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to manipulate it.

```
jq -r .id <<<"$b"
```

If you want to retain the quotes, drop the `-r` option.

Regardless of the tool you use, *always* put shell variables in double quotes unless you specifically require the shell to perform word splitting and wildcard expansion on the value.

The struggle to educate practitioners to use structure-aware tools for structured data has reached [epic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) heights and continues unabated.  Before you decide to use the quick and dirty approach, at least make sure you understand the dangers (technical and mental).

Comment: Agreed, that was a JSON tool would be apt here. But I was looking to solve this without a dependency on the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 echo $b | sed 's/.*: \([^\}]*\)\}/\1/'
```

Or else,

```
 echo $b | sed 's/.*id: \([^\}]*\)\}/\1/'
```